# Matlab generating files fails after 1

Tags: matlab, file-io, eval, metaprogramming

Pre-edit: This bug disappeared for now but I don't know why, so I'd love an answer but don't bother as its a little bit of a waste of your time.

I am taking a list of names and if they don't already have a class I am generating one. (Just for snobs, I know feval isn't secure, but this is a tool for me alone.)

The problem is that each time I run the code it fails after the first new one, not on the fprintf but in the feval. If I just let it fail and then run it again it moves onto the next one, having successfully executed the one it previously failed on. At first I thought it might be a timing error, but it doesn't seem to be one, unless the delay is greater than 10 seconds. Any ideas?

edit: The error I get is Too many output arguments.

```
for i=1:len
    if ~exist([path,'\',obj.Values{i}],'file')
        next = fopen([path,'\',obj.Values{i},'.m'],'w');
        fprintf(next,...
            ['classdef ',obj.Values{i},'\n'...
            ,'    properties\n'...
            ,'        \n'...
            ,'    end\n'...
            ,'    methods\n'...
            ,'        function obj = ',obj.Values{i},'(gui)\n'...
            ,'            \n'...
            ,'        end\n'...
            ,'    end\n'...
            ,'end']);
        fclose(next);
    end
    obj.Children(obj.Values{i})= feval(obj.Values{i},obj);
end
```

Comment: Show the actual error you get, including all line numbers.

Comment: @horchler I was just trying to recreate it and it seems to have gone away over night, which scares me. But I can't get the exact error. Sorry.